Why does Arabic transliterate the Hebrew ץ as س and not ص?
From this Wiktionary entry:

word-final form of צ; final sadhe, tsadi, tzaddik

From the Wiktionary entry for sadhe:

Arabic: صَاد (ar) m (ṣād), ص (ar) (ṣ) (symbol)

Example of a hebrew word with that letter in Arabic Wikipedia:

كيبوتس أو (مستوطنة زراعية وعسكرية) (بالعبرية: קיבוץ وتعني تجمّـُع أو القَبَض وجمعها بالعبرية קיבוצים «كيبوتسيم»، أو بالعربية «كيبوتسات») هي بؤر استيطانية تضم جماعة من المزارعين أو العمال المستوطنين الذين يعيشـون ويعملون سـوياً، ويبلغ عـددهم ما بين 40 و1500 عضو.

Now look at the same word in the Persian Wikipedia:

کیبوتص (عبری: קִבּוּץ / קיבוץ؛ به معنی گردهمایی، خوشه‌بندی) یک جامعه هدفمند در اسرائیل است که به‌طور سنتی بر پایه کشاورزی بنا شده است.

In the Persian Wikipedia the hebrew letter is transliterated as ص.
Why doesn't Arabic transliterate that letter as ص while the latter is originally an Arabic letter?

Persian is not Arabic.

@EmilJeřábek Persian language isn't Arabic language. But we are talking about alphabet here. ص is an Arabic letter, not Persian. Persian alphabet is Arabic, except for 4 extra letters that don't exist in Arabic (of course, those extra letters still are written with Arabic structure).

@EmilJeřábek Also, it seems you haven't looked at the first two links I have provided in my question. The first link says that the said hebrew letter is equal to sadhe. The second link says sadhe is the Arabic letter ص.

Persian uses a modified version of the Arabic script, yes. But it is a different language, with different phonology, therefore different correspondences of letters to sounds, and therefore with different preferences how to transliterate letters from foreign writing systems. That ص historically comes from the same Phoenician letter as צ is irrelevant, really. E.g., transliteration of Arabic or Greek letters to languages using the Latin script also completely ignores the shared origins of the three scripts, and it heavily depends on the target language.

@EmilJeřábek In Persian, ث، س، and ص all are pronounced as /s/. The /s/ sound existed in Iran before the invasion of Arabs and they only had a single letter for it. But after Arabs conquered the country from Sassanids and Arabic language became the formal language in all of the Islamic lands the other two letters were introduced to Iranians which had different pronunciations. The Phoenician alphabet initially was obtained by Arabs to make the Abjad system using their own script. Persians used Abjad only because they were influenced by the Arabic culture since the invasion.

@EmilJeřábek In transliteration of Arabic to languages using the Latin script some punctuations are used. For example, ص is transliterated as an S with a dot below it in English.

In Persian, ث، س، and ص all are pronounced as /s/. Right. But in Arabic, ص is not pronounced as /s/, and therefore it is inadequate to transliterate Modern Hebrew צ, which is pronouced /ts/. Again, all the historical origins are irrelevant to current usage.

@EmilJeřábek So why does that Wiktionary page suggest that that hebrew letter is equal to Arabic ص?

@EmilJeřábek Why do Persians use ص for that hebrew letter while it is pronounced the same with س in Iran?

It does not say that it is equal. And again and again, the fact that both letters are cognates as “the eighteenth letter of many Semitic alphabets/abjads” says nothing about their suitability for being transliterated by each other in modern languages, for which the current sound of the letters is much more important. Words often change spelling even between different language using the same script.

@EmilJeřábek 18th letter in the Phoenician alphabet. 14th letter in Arabic. 17th letter in Persian.

This is too long for a single comment and therefore disguised as an answer. It is a remark on the series of comments below the original question.

Transliteration is not a feature of scripts but of languages. The transliteration of Russian Cyrillic differs considerably for the three major European languages (English, French, and German), and it shows also historic differences. Those differences are a headache for librarians and historians, especially when tracking named entities.


1a. Transliteration is also dependent on the source language. Cyrillic letter Г is transcribed in German as G when the source language is Russian, Bulgarian or Serbian, but as H when the source language is Belarusian or Ukrainian.


There is a difference between historical identity in the sense that some letters can be traced to the same root (in the case of the alphabetical scripts this is a letter of the Phoenician alphabet) and present-day transliteration. Because of divergence in pronunciation the cognate letters are no longer the best transliteration, compare Russian Cyrillic В that is cognate (and, in fact identical in shape for the capital letter) to Latin B but that is transliterated as V (English and French) or W (German) and in more loose transcription it can even become FF (in French, historically) at the end of a word.
Transliteration is not round-trip safe, i.e., a letter transliterated from language A to B may not be recovered by a backtransliteration from B to A. A good example is the German letter H that is traditionally transliterated to Russian Cyrillic Г that is than backtransliterated as German G. Throwing in English, the originally German surname Fichtenholz comes back from Russian as Fikhtengolts.
There are some transliteration systems that try to cure some of the problems above, those are called scientific transliteration or standardised transliteration, but those systems aren't used much outside specialised scientific publications and library catalogues. Test case: Have you ever seen the Latin letter Ŝ (S with circumflex) as a transliteration of the Cyrillic letter Щ (Shch or Šč) in the wild?


You are asking specifically about the (modern) Arabic spelling of the (modern) Hebrew word Kibbutz and why this word has qoph and tzade in Hebrew, but kaf and ta plus sin in Arabic. The answer quite simply is that Arabic has borrowed this word not from Hebrew but from English.

What about soap which is סַבּוֹן in Hebrew and صابون in Arabic? Both are pronounced nearly identical. But here the Hebrew word has סַ which is س in Arabic. But Arabs use ص instead.

Bizarre conclusion. Israeli Hebrew qoph is a plain velar /k/, like Arabic kaf but unlike Arabic qaf, and Hebrew tsade is an affricate /t͡s/, unlike Arabic ṣad /sˤ/. Whether or not the word passed through English wouldn't even affect anything.

@Cairnarvon Israeli Hebrew? Do we also have other Hebrews?

@SnackExchange Yes. Israeli Hebrew is a common way of distinguishing the Hebrew used as an everyday spoken language in Israel from the liturgical various liturgical Hebrews still in use. Modern Hebrew is the other common term, but is a bit of a misnomer as the various liturgical Hebrews are still in modern use (just not as an everyday spoken language). There are significant differences in pronunciation, and Temani and many Sephardi Hebrew pronunciations don't have a plain velar /k/ for qoph

@Tristan Is Yiddish also one of those Hebrews?

@SnackExchange no. Yiddish is a Germanic language, not a Semitic one. Traditional Ashkenazi, Mirachi, Temani, and Sephardi liturgical Hebrews are Semitic
